# Manipulating multidimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

My inputs are several, irregular, multi-dimensional arrays containing floating point numbers, looking something like this:

```
[[[0.34774399349216734, -0.49837251730235765, 0.12359046385526962, 0.03052580675850769], 
[0.9030134040537152, -0.7537158452634996, 0.2910583603657293, -0.22034711903454673]], 
[[-0.9383578579687082, -0.2281750912629248, 0.052722557936115466]]]
```

The numbers of layers, and number of items in each list is the same within an instance of an object, but will differ between objects.

What I need is a way to generate indexes for each of these items in turn, so they can be used on multiple lists of the same format. I'm currently lost at where even to start.

EDIT: By indexes I mean a way to access corresponding items in different lists.

Comment: consider using numpy?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for. Can you provide an example of what these indexes look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[[1,2,3,4,5],[3,1,4,2,5],[2,1,4,6,3]],
[[1,2,3],[4,2,6]],
[[3,6,7],[7,4,6],[2,1,4]]]
```

You can access all the elements like this:

```
for lists in array:
    for list in lists:
        for num in list:
            print num
```

So to get the first element in each list:

```
for lists in array:
    for list in lists:
            print list[0]
```

Or if you already know the dimensions of your array why not just reference them directly:

```
array [0][0][0]
```

or using your notation:

```
array [i][j][k]
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` lets you index multidimensional arrays with syntax such as `array[1,2,3]`. It does this by overriding item getters to accept a `tuple` instead of an integer or hashable object like lists and dicts. But `numpy` isn't so graceful when dealing with arrays whose dimensions vary, so you won't have much luck simply switching to `numpy`.

You can use a similar technique though. Your index can be a `tuple` (or any sequence, really) and then its just a case of writing the supporting framework. Since building a class can be complicated, all I've done is implemented a single function that indexes using a `tuple` and I've added a enumeration function for test.

```
array = [[[0.34774399349216734, -0.49837251730235765, 0.12359046385526962, 0.03052580675850769], 
[0.9030134040537152, -0.7537158452634996, 0.2910583603657293, -0.22034711903454673]], 
[[-0.9383578579687082, -0.2281750912629248, 0.052722557936115466]]]

def array_enum(array):
    """enumerate multidimensional array returning indextuple, value for
    each leaf node value.
    """
    for i, item in enumerate(array):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for subindex, val in array_enum(item):
                yield (i,) + subindex, val
        else:
            yield (i,), item 

def array_get_item(array, indextuple):
    """Use index values in indextuple to return item from
    multidimensional array.
    """
    for i in indextuple[:-1]:
        array = array[i]
    return array[indextuple[-1]]

for indextuple, val in array_enum(array):
    orig_val = array_get_item(array, indextuple)
    print(indextuple, val, orig_val, val == orig_val)
```

The result for your example array is

```
(0, 0, 0) 0.34774399349216734 0.34774399349216734 True
(0, 0, 1) -0.49837251730235765 -0.49837251730235765 True
(0, 0, 2) 0.12359046385526962 0.12359046385526962 True
(0, 0, 3) 0.03052580675850769 0.03052580675850769 True
(0, 1, 0) 0.9030134040537152 0.9030134040537152 True
(0, 1, 1) -0.7537158452634996 -0.7537158452634996 True
(0, 1, 2) 0.2910583603657293 0.2910583603657293 True
(0, 1, 3) -0.22034711903454673 -0.22034711903454673 True
(1, 0, 0) -0.9383578579687082 -0.9383578579687082 True
(1, 0, 1) -0.2281750912629248 -0.2281750912629248 True
(1, 0, 2) 0.052722557936115466 0.052722557936115466 True
```